# .Net application settings path

Tags: .net, settings

By default in windows application setting are saved in this directory:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\<Company Name>\<appdomainname>_<eid>_<hash>\<version>\user.config
```

Is it possible to change path for saving user.config file? 
For example save it in local folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can, if you make your own ApplicationSettingsBase derived class to manage the application settings.

For details, see [Application Settings Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx).

That being said, I strongly recommend not doing this.  Using a local folder (local to your app) will require your application to run under elevated permissions on Vista and Windows 7, which is an unnecessary annoyance.  User settings files should be configurable via your application, and not something the user ever needs to see or hand-edit...