# Application not reading my.settings correctly on load when moved or copied from folder?

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++

Here is my code:

```
Public ATTEMPTS As Integer = My.Settings.ATTEMPTS

Private Sub EKV_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If My.Settings.ATTEMPTS = 3 Then
        Me.Enabled = False
        MSGBOX.Show()
    Else
        VKBox.Select()
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem im having is basically this: the user has three attempts to put in a password to access information. every time the user fails to enter the password correctly I have set up a variable called "ATTEMPTS" in the application settings. Originally the my.settings.ATTEMPTS = 0 but after each try it adds another attempt until ATTEMPTS = 3. I have also already set the application to save the settings every time it adds an attempt so even if they close the application and try again their number of attempts is recorded and saved. When I debug the application in visual basic everything works fine and if attempts = 3 or does not = 3 then it recognizes that and loads the right form. But when I publish the application or even try to move or copy the application from its folder under the visual basic folder to another place, it immediately recognizes that ATTEMPTS = 3 on the first attempt to open the application and loads the wrong form, but when I move the application back into the folder it recognizes ATTEMPTS = 0 and loads the right form???? I have already tried enabling the make a single instance application option and nothing else I am trying is working!? Please help.

Comment: You need to understand where the settings are actually being saved. Once you understand that I think it will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings are saved in path [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488277/net-application-settings-path). And the hash value which is path of the leaf directory is dependent on directory of your EXE file. So every time you move your EXE, new settings are created. You can use several approaches:

- Override how settings save location is determined and make the location fixed – see the above linked answer. (But save them near their current location, not with EXE.)
- Save settings in the registry instead of settings file.
- Scan all settings folders of your application (old and new, they are together) and find settings file with most recent date/time. Read the value from that file and import it into your settings.