# Visual Studio suddely shows "Object reference needed"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, settings

I'm working on a project, that now needs to store something. Since I added a value to the settings (right-click project --> properties --> settings) I'm unable to build the software. The `Settings.Designer.vb` says a object reference is missing for `My.Settings.Save()`. Until now everything worked fine. Can anyone help?

EDIT:
Okay, literally one minute after posting this question i got it fixed, by changing `My.Settings.Save()` to `My.Settings.Default.Save()`. Can anyone explain?

Comment: You should start using source control immediately. That way, if anything goes haywire for whatever reason, you can simply revert to the last known good version.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm fighting for it, but my company thinks, this is not needed...

Comment: Depending on what level of control you have over what software is installed, you could run git locally even if there isn't anything "official".  You wouldn't get the collaboration or resiliency benefits, but you would get the history-tracking benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Is the property scoped to User? Application-scoped properties cannot be saved at run time beecause the setting is scoped to Users by default. Also save my settings when closing in the project properties application tab is set to true by default, which means that My.Settings.Save is not required.

Comment: Yes, the property is scoped to the user, but the code making trouble is auto generated, so it isn't my choice to execute My.Settings.Save... I tried making changes, but the comment says it's auto generated and changes may get overwritten

Comment: Hello, is your problem solved now?

Comment: Hello, nope. With the workaround described i'm not getting any errors, but i still found no reason...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881415/c-sharp-settings-default-save-not-saving       Then you can take a look at this case, hope it helps you.

Comment: Nope, it did not help. The problem is not, that the data not getting stored. It gets stored. The problem is, that i'm getting an error "Object reference needed". After changing ```My.Settings.Save()``` to ```My.Settings.Default.Save()``` i fixed the error, but i want to understand the reason...