# Default.Settings.Save does not save classes

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the Properties.Settings field in the project. Set the variable type to bool, string etc. When I set it the below code works without any problem. But when I set a class directly in the project as a type, it doesn't save. Settings field can't access the classes in the project?

Data type : ProjectName.Models.SettingsModel, Name : AppSettigs.

Data type : bool, Name : IsRemember.

In the code below, the save process is successful. But when I open the project again, AppSettings returns null.

Code:

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.IsRemember = true;
                   Properties.Settings.Default.AppSettings = new SettingsModel()
                   { 
                        AccentColorItems  = Settings.AccentColorItems,
                        ThemeItems = Settings.ThemeItems,
                        SelectedAccentColor = Settings.SelectedAccentColor,
                        SelectedTheme = Settings.SelectedTheme,
                        SelectedLanguage = Settings.SelectedLanguage,
                        AppNotifications = Settings.AppNotifications,
                        SystemNotifications = Settings.SystemNotifications,
                        AllowAutomaticUpdating = Settings.AllowAutomaticUpdating
                   };
                   Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

I followed the suggestions here, but nothing changed.

[C# Settings.Default.Save() not saving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881415/c-sharp-settings-default-save-not-saving)

Comment: I've not had to use it myself (so won't post as an answer) but I believe settings are saved as XML, meaning you're limited to what can be represented in XML [primitive types, lists, etc]

Comment: Yes, I guess as you mentioned. I solved the problem by serializing and saving.

Comment: XML serialization saves public properties with a getter and a setter, not fields.

Comment: I didn't do XML serialization. I serialized it in JSON format.