# Settings.settings: where can I find the stored values?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

The question is simple: Can I see the stored values of my application configuration? Not at running time.

The only thing I see in app.config is this:

```
        <setting name="myvariable" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
```

In my code I did a `Save()` but why I can't see the values in the file?

Comment: Settings.settings is saved as user specific data. This might help you more,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982354/where-are-the-properties-default-settings-stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Settings.settings` simply describes the design-time contents for user-specific settings. The actual runtime file which is created is `user.config` which can be found under the `AppData` folder under your specific Windows username and related to your application and the specific assembly that has the `Settings.settings` file within it.

If you want to check where it is at runtime, check the value of  `Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`