# Application settings reset when exe changes location

Tags: c#, forms, config

Hi I'm using the Visual Studio config files, however the settings change every time I move the exe.

How can I fix this?

### app.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="GUIChangerUI.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <userSettings>
        <GUIChangerUI.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="StarmadePath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>default</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="GuiPath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Not selected yet.</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="FirstStart" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="jpeg" serializeAs="String">
                <value>default</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="debug" serializeAs="String">
                <value>default</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Darktheme" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Lightheme" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="starmadeStarter" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
            <setting name="_starmadeStarter" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
            <setting name="OSMTheme" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
        </GUIChangerUI.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user settings will be stored in your user's profile in such a way that the location of your application is linked. That's why the application, when moved, does not find the settings anymore.

What you can try to do is:

1. Create a new user setting named `SettingsUpgradeRequired` and set it to `true` in the settings designer in Visual Studio.
2. In your application's startup code, check whether `SettingsUpgradeRequired` is `true` and if so, perform a settings upgrade.

As the new setting will *only* be true after the settings file was reset, the following should import the old settings, and it should do so only once:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.SettingsUpgradeRequired)
{
    try
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
        Properties.Settings.Default.SettingsUpgradeRequired = false;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
       ... // Upgrade failed - tell the user or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesent work, it reconizes that the config file is missing but wont update it

Comment: Are you sure? It won't copy a new exe.config to the folder with the executable, but it should restore the previous user settings.

Comment: yes it works now, I had the SettingsUpgradeRecuired wrong

Answer (score 5):

The actual configuration file containing saved configuration settings is stored here:

```
%APPDATA%\Local\<application name>\<application name>.<eid>_<hash>\<version>
```

According to [this MSDN article:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379611(v=vs.80).aspx):

> `<eid>` is the URL, StrongName, or Path, based on the evidence available to hash.
>   `<hash>` is a SHA1 hash of evidence gathered from the CurrentDomain, in the following order of preference:
>   StrongName
>   URL
>   **If neither of these is available, use the .exe path.**

*(my emphasis)*

So the solution seems simple:

> **Create a strong name and sign your executable.**

Then you will get the same unique hash every time and it won't change whenever you start the executable from a new location.

If you need help signing your application, please refer to this MSDN article: [How to: Sign an Assembly with a Strong Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thats the right answer. It will solve the OPs problem (moving exe file). However, if the version of the application changes, the settings will be lost again, right?

Comment: He must call `Upgrade` on the settings, there is another answer here that details how to do this and though that answer doesn't answer why the settings are cleared/forgotten when the executable is moved, he needs to handle this case as well.

Comment: Okay this works perfectly <3, but i had to sign some dlls i had with my key.

Comment: Note that this path (and its explanation) is outdated as of later .NET versions. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/982354/1688738 for more.

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is by design because you could have multiple versions of you application (for instance a QA version, a PROD version and so on) that requires different setting storages. See also [Client Settings FAQ](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rprabhu/2005/06/29/client-settings-faq/) for details.

If you need a settings management that is independend of the location / version of you app, i would suggest wo create your own settings file and store them below "%appdata%[company][application]"