# C# Properties wont save

Tags: c#, xml, raspberry-pi, settings, user.config

I want to save settings between two sessions.

I change the value, save it, close the program and its still the old one... WHY?

```
int test = Properties.Settings.Default.mode;
        System.Console.WriteLine(test);
        Properties.Settings.Default.mode = 1;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        test = Properties.Settings.Default.mode;
        System.Console.WriteLine(test);
```

XML:

```
<userSettings>
    <PyControl.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="mode" serializeAs="String">
            <value>0</value>
        </setting>
    </PyControl.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you were finding the settings file in wrong place? It isn't in your bin folder.

> Your application will have a settings folder under
>   %userprofile%\appdata\local or %userprofile%\Local
>   Settings\Application Data depending on which version of Windows you're
>   running, for settings that are user specific. If you store settings
>   for all users, then they'll be in the corresponding folder under
>   C:\users or C:\Documents and Settings for all user profiles (ex:
>   C:\users\public\appdata\local).

Ref: [Where are the Properties.Settings.Default stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982354/where-are-the-properties-settings-default-stored)

Edit:

Assume if you're NOT using Windows IoT, try `~/.config/{AppName}/user.config`? I don't write C# on RPi but above link mentioned this folder. -- If not here, I'm sorry that I can't offer further help :(

Comment: User settings don't get saved in that `Program.exe.config` file, though - the user doesn't ordinarily have permission to write to that file. They get saved in a similarly named file somewhere the user has permission to write to (per the linked question).

Comment: @DanielBucher Assume if you're NOT using Windows IoT, try `~/.config/{AppName}/user.config`?

Comment: The Folder with my Application is not present in the .config folder