# How to detect a property value of the setting file is changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, installation

I have tried to make a simple user Authorization. **After installation, the property called "UserHasBeenVerified" in the Settings1 file, is changed.** I have added Settings Changed event handler to App.cs file but still I don't know the reason. **I want the property to be FALSE after the installation. But somehow it does be TRUE.**

Do you think how I can solve this problem? Thank you.

---

I have created an Installer Class to reset the Settings1 after the installation:

```
 [RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class InstallerClass : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public InstallerClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        // This function runs when the installation is finished.

        base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);

        try
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show($"01\nVERIFIED STATE: {BackendLayer.Settings1.Default.UserHasBeenVerified}"); // Shows: VERIFIED STATE: False
            BackendLayer.Settings1.Default.Reset();
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show($"02\nVERIFIED STATE: {BackendLayer.Settings1.Default.UserHasBeenVerified}"); // Shows: VERIFIED STATE: False
            BackendLayer.Settings1.Default.Save();
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show($"03\nVERIFIED STATE: {BackendLayer.Settings1.Default.UserHasBeenVerified}"); // Shows: VERIFIED STATE: False
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Installed");
        }
        catch 
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("NOT Installed");
        }
    }


}
```

And the App.cs file is:

```
App() 
{
// Runs first whenever the program is opened
    BackendLayer.Settings1.Default.SettingChanging += Default_SettingChanging;
    MessageBox.Show($"VERIFIED STATE: {BackendLayer.Settings1.Default.UserHasBeenVerified}"); // Shows: VERIFIED STATE: TRUE

}
private void Default_SettingChanging(object sender, System.Configuration.SettingChangingEventArgs e)
{
// Fires when any property in setting1 is changed.
   MessageBox.Show($"Setting Name: {e.SettingName}\nSetting Key: {e.SettingKey}\nSetting Class: {e.SettingClass}\nNew value: {e.NewValue}");
}
```

The function that calls App() Constructor:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Application Entry Point.
    /// </summary>
    [System.STAThreadAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
    public static void Main() {
        ScheduleProgram.App app = new ScheduleProgram.App();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
    }
```

UserHasBeenVerified Code in Settings1.Designer.cs:

```
 [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("False")]
    public bool UserHasBeenVerified {
        get {
            return ((bool)(this["UserHasBeenVerified"]));
        }
        set {
            this["UserHasBeenVerified"] = value;
        }
    }
```

**The program's output after the installation by order:**

1. 01\nVERIFIED STATE: False
2. 02\nVERIFIED STATE: False
3. 03\nVERIFIED STATE: False
4. Installed

**The program's output after it is opened:**

5. VERIFIED STATE: True

**The things that I have tried:**

I have changed these properties of the Settings1 file:

```
*Build Action: From "None" to "Content"* ,

*Copy to Output Directory: From "Do not copy" to "Copy always"*
```

Comment: If you open the Settings file in the installer and print its content what do you see for the value of `UserHasBeenVerified`? I don't think `BackendLayer.Settings1.Default` is getting you the value from the file when you call it in the installer, you're getting the value from an instance of the Settings1 class instantiated with the default constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @HasaniH You are probably right. But how can I get the value from the file when I call it in the installer to reset all the setting values? I just want to reset all the properties of the Setting1 file to their default values. (In my case, the default value of `UserHasBeenVerified` is False).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't package the settings file with the necessary values already set? That would be easier than trying to manually edit the file.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What's the value of `UserHasBeenVerified` in your `Settings1.settings` designer file in your project? When you build your project does the same value get copied to your app.config under the `BackendLayer.Settings1` section?

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't change. I understood now why it didn't change. I should have again to set the Copy to Output Directory: From "Do not copy" to "Copy always". Then it worked. Thank you for your answer @HasaniH . You are right, I need to package the settings file like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `BackendLayer.Settings1.Default` is getting you the value from the file when you call it in the installer, you're getting the value from an instance of the Settings1 class instantiated with the default constructor.

Confirm that the value of `UserHasBeenVerified` is correct in your `Settings1.settings` file and that it's being copied to your `app.config` when you build your application. Since you just need default values, your installer just needs to package the output from building your app

Comment: You are completely right! I found another solution too. In installer class, I could delete [the folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982354/where-are-the-properties-settings-default-stored) where the Settings files are saved on. Thank you for your answer again.