# Looking for information regarding user.config files and what causes these to be created by a .NET Framework application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, user-config

I am terribly sorry if this isn't the right place to ask but what I am hoping is that someone can explain what is going on in plain English.

We're CompanyA and we were recently bought over by CompanyB. Our application was called after our Company, so for simplicity's sake let's say that we wrote an App and it was built as CompanyA.exe

Our App creates a folder %localappdata%\CompanyA where we put "our stuff"

Our app is a WPF Application written for .NET Framework 4.8 using primarily VB.NET. Our application is signed with a .SNK file

When we were bought over we changed the Company Name in the Assembly Information to
"CompanyA, a CompanyB solution", but we still build the application as CompanyA.exe

Now here's the weird thing

We started noticing that a folder was created at
%localappdata%\CompanyA,_a_CompanyB_solution

within that folder would be subfolders named after some of our executables, followed by *Strongname* followed by a bunch of random looking characters, followed by a version foldername

in each of those subfolders would be a user.config file

So, for example, we might find
%localappdata%\CompanyA,*a_CompanyB_solution\CompanyA.exe_StrongName**gibberishhere*\1.2.3.4\user.config
after we build version 1.2.3.4 of application CompanyA.exe

the user.config file would contain very little, and removing any of these files, even the entire %localappdata%\CompanyA,_a_CompanyB_solution folder, makes no difference to how usable the application is. It works fine with or without that folder.

My questions:

1. What causes this to be created? We are not aware of having deliberately changed anything in our application to tell it to create these.
2. What purpose do these files serve?
3. If they are as unimportant as they seem to be (at least to our application), is there anything we can change in our application's configuration to stop it doing this?

Comment: It seems that you haven't mentioned anything about what you use to create an installer for your application. It also seems that you may not have read the documentation for whatever installer that you're using because this is the most likely place you'd find answers to your questions.

Comment: We wrote our own home grown deployment product.

Comment: _We wrote our own home grown deployment product_: Why would anyone here be able to answer questions about the directories that your _home grown_ installer creates? Read the code along with the associated documentation.

Comment: "Why would anyone here be able"
and yet, JonasH just did exactly that.

Comment: @JonasH gave you information that is readily available in the MS documentation if you would have read it. But the particulars really depend on the installer that you've used and the code/options that you've used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the projects properties you should have a "Settings" tab, also accessible from "properties\settings.settings" in the solution explorer.

These settings can be used to store various configurations. Settings have two different scopes:

1. Application: These are stored in "yourprojectName.exe.config" in your program directory, and cannot be changed from within the application itself.
2. User: These are stored in the %LocalAppdata% folder, and is likely the cause of what you are seeing. I'm not sure exactly how it selects the subfolder name, see [Where are the Properties.Settings.Default stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982354/where-are-the-properties-settings-default-stored) for more info. These setting can be changed from within the application.

Try searching for `Settings.Default.Save()`, or just `Default.Save()`, since these are the calls to save the default setting file. You could also try searching for `ConfigurationManager`. That should hopefully give you some hint about where and how these files are used.

Comment: Hm you may be on to something and it might explain why this only gets created *sometimes* ... One thing our software allows the user to so is save a "label printer" and in that code I see: My.Settings.Save() - but that would only be done once in a blue moon by an occasional user, definitely not everyone. Which may explain why we only see these things appearing very occasionally?

Comment: Yes this is EXACTLY what it is! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and the good news is that it confirms that this is nothing we need to worry about

Comment: By the way, My.Settings.Save() turned out to be the same as Settings.Default.Save() on this occasion due to VB creating a "default" instance through Public Shared ReadOnly Property [Default]() As MySettings

Answer (score 1):

These folders and files are created when you add an `app.config` file to the VB project and you add settings that are saved to the file. The settings need to be saved per user on the PC, so the .NET Framework creates these folders to store a particular users' version of the user.config file, which is a subset of the app.config file (the user-saveable values).

> We started noticing that a folder was created at %localappdata%\CompanyA,_a_CompanyB_solution

If you go to the project properties and select "Assembly Information", you will notice that this folder is named after the `Company` value.

> So, for example, we might find %localappdata%\CompanyA,a_CompanyB_solution\CompanyA.exe_StrongNamegibberishhere\1.2.3.4\user.config after we build version 1.2.3.4 of application CompanyA.exe

This folder is named after the executable name, and the user.config file down the folder hierarchy is what stores the users' saved settings.

Comment: Thank you, yes you are correct, it's named after the Company value in Assembly information. We have had an app.config file in the project for quite a long time but we've only started seeing this happening fairly recently. Thanks for pointing me in that direction, I'll have a closer look.

Comment: For info, JonasH above managed to talk me right to the statement that causes the files to appear and helped me realise it was all good. Thank you for your input, all the same, it was also helpful