# Can't get app.config file path

Tags: vb.net, app-config, configuration-files

I want to get the path of my `app.config` file, but it can't fetch it. Here is the method I've been trying:

```
Public Shared Function GetConfiguration(Optional ByVal fileName As String = "")
Dim map As System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap = New ExeConfigurationFileMap()
    'read file from given path
    Dim objApplicationIdentity As New ApplicationIdentity("")

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) Then
        map.ExeConfigFilename = "~" & fileName ' the root web.config  
    Else
        map.ExeConfigFilename = "..\\app.config" ' the root web.config  
    End If
    ''read cogfiguration settings
    strConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None)


End Function
```

How can I obtain the path?

Comment: the config file is only named `app.config` at design time. When compiled it becomes `name_of_executeable.exe.config`

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793657/how-to-find-path-of-active-app-config-file