# app.config references to source code path instead of dll path

Tags: c#, app-config

I am developing an add-in for excel

In excel i am adding reference to the dll file created and using functions from that

example

```
Set o = CreateObject("DllName.PublishFile")
```

here I have added reference to a `.tlb` file 
i.e in excel i pressed `alt+f11` to goto macros, i clicked on tools, clicked on reference and added the `.tlb` file by browsing to the path of the file

the location of this file is

```
C:/Program Files/Project/Bin/Debug
```

In the code , to get path of `app.config` i have used

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase
```

to get the location of dll i.e    `D:/ProjectName/Bin/Debug`

After this, i used installshield to create installer and installed it

Now the location of the dll is `C:/Program Files/Project/`

Here i have app.config, dll.config etc

After installation, I changed the reference of the dll

i.e i selected .tlb file in `C:/Program Files/Project/` instead of the .tlb file located in `D:/ProjectName/Bin/Debug`. But it is still getting config values from the app.config in Bin/Debug!!

How can i get the values from app.config in dll's folder here?

in short 
I want the path of the dll/tlb file which i have referred to in the excel macro i.e `C:/Program Files/ProjectName`
But it is taking the app.config present in source code path i.e `D:/project/bin/debug`

Comment: Removing VBA tag, Visual Basic for Applications has nothing to do with .NET.

Comment: Question is unclear: do you want the path of the config file (that is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793657/how-to-find-path-of-active-app-config-file)) or the path to the current assembly (in which case you have the code in the question)?

Comment: I want the path of the dll/tlb file which i have referred to in the excel i.e C:/Program Files/ProjectName
But it is taking the app.config present in source code path i.e D:/project/bin/debug

Comment: This is still unclear. You keep giving directory names as if they are path names. And then you thrown in references to Excel (data content or automation of Excel: also unclear). Remember we know only what you write in the question.

Comment: @Richard I have added details to the question

Comment: That's much better. I suspect each time you build you are registering the new build, thus instantiating that copy from Excel. I would start by checking the COM registration information in the registry.

Answer (score 1):

GetExecutingAssembly() returns the currently executing assembly (e.g. *.exe*).

Let's assume you have a type **Class1** defined in your DLL, then you could use this to find the path to your library.

```
string s = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (Class1)).CodeBase;
```

Comment: `GetExecutingAssembly()` will get the `Assembly` instance for the assembly containing the currently executing code: it will only be the exe for code directly in that exe. (To always get the exe use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`.)